Is it possible to create new edges in Bloom using Scene Action that DO NOT get merged into the current database?
I've tried to build queries in Bloom using Scene Actions that not only find nodes but create new relationships between the output nodes by using MERGE ()-[]-(). However this always creates new edges that alter the current database. Is it possible to create a relationship (edge) "virtually" during the scene action that only shows up in the scene, but does not update the this into the database (so it can be later cleared from the scene)?
Here is the kind of query I've done for a scene in Bloom:
MATCH (e1)<-[re]-(p1)
MATCH (p1)<-[sr]-(t1)-[rs]->(p2)
MATCH (p2)-[re2]->(e2)
WHERE id(e1) in $nodes
MERGE (e1)-[new_rel]-(e2)
RETURN e1,new_rel,e2

... but unfortunately it adds "new_rel" into the database, which I don't want.

You can use the apoc procedure apoc.create.vRelationship to create virtual relationships for display purposes (e.g., in Bloom).  And you can use OPTIONAL MATCH and call subquery post-union processing to do some conditional processing to mimic MERGE behavior.
The following Bloom "Saved cypher" action may work for you:
MATCH (e1)<--()<--()-->()-->(e2)
WHERE id(e1) in $nodes
OPTIONAL MATCH (e1)-[existing_rel:FOO]->(e2)
CALL {
  WITH existing_rel, e1, e2
  WITH existing_rel, e1, e2
  WHERE existing_rel IS NULL
  CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(e1, 'FOO', {}, e2) YIELD rel
  RETURN rel AS new_rel

  UNION

  WITH existing_rel
  WITH existing_rel
  WHERE existing_rel IS NOT NULL
  RETURN existing_rel AS new_rel
}
RETURN e1, new_rel, e2

Note, however, that the above query will not be able to detect already-existing virtual nodes from a previous run of the action, since they do not actually exist in the DB. You will have to clear the scene to delete existing virtual relationships.

Thanks cybersam - it works! But I don't understand why having 2 successive WITH clauses ( WITH existing_rel, e1, e2) works and 1 doesn't?

The first WITH in a CALL subquery is for importing variables. See here.
